# Why does Keras model predict function report warning and error about wrong shape of a image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to tensorflow and I tried to use the Keras MNIST dataset to train a neutral network. But when I called the model.predict() function right after the fit() function, tensorflow reported the WARNING and ERROR like below:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28) for input Tensor("flatten_input:0", shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28).

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 28]

Here is my code:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))

train_images_scaled = train_images/255
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images_scaled, train_labels, epochs=5)

model.predict(test_images[2]) #Error here
```

And I checked the shape of test_images[2] using `test_images[2].shape`
It's true that the shape is (28, 28).

I'm really confused, any help here?

Comment: You forgot the first dimension (batch dimension). Actually test_images[2] shape should be (1,28,28). Because you are passing 1 sample.

Comment: Change it like this: `model.predict(np.reshape(test_image[2],(1,28,28)))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by saying `test_images[2]` you are removing the batch dimension.  Predict works on batches not single images.  So to predict a single image you should pass in something of shape (1, 28, 28) instead of (28, 28).  You could try `model.predict(np.expand_dims(test_images[2], 0))[0]` which will add the batch dimension back in.  Also note that the prediction returns a list of predictions which is why you need to take the first element from the returned result.